# Simultaneous Contour and 3d Plot

Tags: plot, julia, contour

I'm trying to simultaneously plot the contour lines and the surface of a function in Julia, but I can't seem to find a way to that.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I worked out for `Plots`. The `PyPlot` package has something better, and something could be done with Makie:

```
import Contour: contours, levels, level, lines, coordinates

function surface_contour(xs, ys, f; offset=0)
  p = surface(xs, ys, f, legend=false, fillalpha=0.5)

  ## we add to the graphic p, then plot
  zs = [f(x,y) for x in xs, y in ys]  # reverse order for use with Contour package
  for cl in levels(contours(xs, ys, zs))
    lvl = level(cl) # the z-value of this contour level
    for line in lines(cl)
        _xs, _ys = coordinates(line) # coordinates of this line segment
        _zs = offset .+ 0 .* _xs
        plot!(p, _xs, _ys, _zs, alpha=0.5)        # add curve on x-y plane
    end
  end
  p
end

xs = ys = range(-pi, stop=pi, length=100)
f(x,y) = 2 + sin(x) - cos(y)

surface_contour(xs, ys, f)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :) However, the contour lines overlap with the surface plot, is there any way for the surface plot to be the top layer?

Comment: I managed to fix it by plotting the surface plot right before the end of the function, that way the surface plot becomes the top layer.

Comment: The `offset` argument lets you shift the z-level where the contour is plotted. But I'm hoping you get a better answer to this question, as I was never so satisfied with how this one needs manual adjustment for the offset.